# Class bound protocol with private(set) requirement

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a `Nameable` protocol meant to be used on `NSManagedObjects`.  This protocol is declared in its own Swift package and is meant to be imported by many other packages, so the protocol needs to be public.  I also need to maintain the protocol approach rather than using a base class with inheritance. I would like to validate my names and throw errors using the below default implementation, but there seems to be no way to enforce that a developer uses `set(_ name: String)`.

```swift
import CoreData

public protocol Nameable: NSManagedObject {
    /// The name property of the entity
    /// - Warning: **don't** set this directly, use `set(_ name: String)` to ensure the name is validated
    ///
    /// - Note: This needs to be an `@NSManaged`
    var name: String { get set }
    
    static var defaultName: String { get }
    
    static var maxNameLength: Int { get }
    
    func set(_ name: String) throws
}
public extension Nameable {
    // TODO: Localize
    static var defaultName: String { "Untitled" }
    
    static var maxNameLength: Int { 128 }
    
    func set(_ name: String) throws {
        guard !name.isEmpty else { throw NameError.nameEmpty }
        guard name.count <= Self.maxNameLength else { throw NameError.nameTooLong }
        self.name = name
        try managedObjectContext?.save()
    }
}

public enum NameError: Error {
    case nameEmpty
    case nameTooLong
}
```

I would like to use the protocol like so:

```swift
@objc(MyObject)
class MyObject: NSManagedObject, Nameable {
  @NSManaged public private(set) var name: String
}
```

But since the protocol is public, name also needs to be publicly settable. The only solutions that I have come up with are "soft" (ie. warning comments, or something like `@NSManaged var unsafeName: String { get set }`).  Is there any way to achieve the desired results that can be enforced by the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an internal `MutableNameable` protocol refining your Nameable protocol:

```swift
public protocol Nameable: NSManagedObject {
    var name: String { get }
    // ...
}

public extension Nameable {
    // ...
}

internal protocol MutableNameable: Nameable {
    var name: String { get set }
}
```

In your client:

```swift
extension MutableNameable {
    // ...
}
```

this would allow you to have :

```swift
@objc(MyObject)
class MyObject: NSManagedObject, MutableNameable {
  @NSManaged public internal(set) var name: String
}
```

`MutableNameable` could also be private but it would force you to have all conforming types in the same file.

This won't be part of your package and only be usable by one client, but if you want to stick with protocols, I think your only other alternative is a public setter.

Comment: This won't work since the objects are expected to be declared in the client.  `MyObject` couldn't adopt the internal `MutableNameable` protocol since it would be declared in the client not the package.

Comment: You can define `MutableNameable` wherever you need to. But I don't see any other way to do it with protocols.